# SpringBoot Profiles for datasource properties

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, datasource, jndi

I'm starting to use Spring Boot and believe i understand how to override property file values with environment specific property files. E.g. if I have an **application.properties** file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:server.co.uk:10010/database_dev
spring.datasource.username=dev_username
spring.datasource.password=dev_password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
```

and an **application-test.properties** file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:server.co.uk:10010/database_test
spring.datasource.username=test_username
spring.datasource.password=test_password
```

then if I pass in the test profile as a vm arg, the username, password and url will come from the **application-test.properties** file and the driver-class-name from **application.properties**.

So far so good.....

However what I want to do is

running locally with **application.properties**, use

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:server.co.uk:10010/database_dev
spring.datasource.username=dev_username
spring.datasource.password=dev_password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
```

but running in test with **application-test.properties**, use

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/my_jndi_name
```

From my understanding, the problem is that the **application-test.properties** file will only 'override' properties of the same name, whereas I need to access my datasource in a different way in test/prod to how I am locally.

An alternative solution may be to use a jndi locally as well althopugh I'm unsure how to configure this in Spring Boot with an embedded tomcat server, (I use websphere in the higher environments)

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Have you tried it...

Answer (score 2):

Use two different profiles, one 'prod' and one 'test', and make sure you do not declare any properties in application.properties that may conflict with application-test.properties or application-prod.properties

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to approach this by using jndi lookups both locally and in the higher environments (test and prod). So instead of using different application properties depending on environment (e.g. datasource.username and datasource.password in local and datasource.jndi-name in test and prod), I now just use datasource.jndi-name in all environments.

I do have a remaining issue in that one of the datasources wires correctly whilst the other fails but I'll post that as a separate question as its a different issue from this question.